# Javascript - Change text of div if id equals 'test'

Tags: javascript, date

**Thanks everybody for downvoting... `var date = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds); doesn't work!`**

New question: How to I change the text inside of a div to true or false?
Code:

```
function getDate() {
var today = new Date();
var year = today.getFullYear();
var month = today.getMonth()+1;
var day = today.getDate();
var hours = today.getHours();
var minutes = today.getMinutes();
var seconds = today.getSeconds();
var milliseconds = today.getMilliseconds();
var date = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
var date2 = new Date(2014,11,1,22,00,00);
if (date === date2) {
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "true";
}
else
{
document.getElementById("false").innerHTML = "false";
}
}
```

For some reason this doesn't work :(, and yes, the div has test as id
-Bram

Comment: Did you see the documentation (any one) of the Date object ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: Read this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp `new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);`

Comment: **Non** w3schools link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: It should be saying something, Or just it **Doesn't work**?

Comment: @bramhaag Is `var date` global or local variable?

Comment: If you want to use it outside of function, you should return `Date` or set global variable, otherwise I don't see where you problem is.

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/matjazmav/86h4Lo8L/

Answer (score 2):

please read some documentation first: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp

```
var date = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

Comment: I already used this method, but for some reason it just doesn't work. Thanks everybody for downvoting btw...